# Detecting Browser Plugin via Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to check wheather a particular plugin is installed into the client's browser via javascript , and if it is not installed then show user a title Bar (just like in it comes in all kind off browser if some  plugin is missing  to download that Plugin )
for Example : like below

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: You really need to add what browser you're targeting, and a specific plugin if you have one in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [detecting browser plugins](http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-browser-plugins/). Also, you can use [plugin detect library](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/All/).

Comment: how to show a pop-up bar like above image to provide client the option to  downlaod missing  particular plugin